# MySQL 5.1 -> 5.6 problem, select distinct order by limit query stops using index

Tags: mysql, index

I'm testing a MySQL 5.1 -> 5.6 upgrade, and I've run into an issue.

I have a query that hits a ~30 million row table, selecting distinct IDs with an order by/limit restriction.  Sample query is below:

```
select distinct MyTable.id 
from MyTable 
where related_id in (22205, 23805) 
order by name asc, id asc 
limit 50;
```

There are quite a few fields in the table, but these are the only ones being queried upon.  There is an index on related_id, as well as a compound index on (related_id, name).

In MySQL 5.1, it used the related_id index and returned within a second or two.  In MySQL 5.6, it refuses to use any index and takes several minutes.  I've tried forcing index usage as well, explain still shows a full table scan regardless of which index I try to force.  I've analyzed the table as well, no difference.

If I remove the `IN` statement and just use one related_id, it uses an index without issue.  The initial query had a dozen or so related_ids, dropping below the `eq_range_index_dive_limit` parameter (10) made no difference, nor did disabling the dive limit.

So...any idea what's going on here?  Did I miss another new parameter in 5.6?  Or do we think that it believes it will hit the limit with the table scan faster than trying to use an index?  But if that were the case then I'd think I'd still be able to force index usage.

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit** - Additional info I forgot to include:

If I remove any one of the three "trouble" clauses (`DISTINCT`, `ORDER BY`, or `LIMIT`) then it uses the index without issue.  It seems to be the combination of those three, mixed with the `IN` statement in the `WHERE`, that causes the problem.

**Edit 2** - Original hibernate generated query (minus table/column renames):

```
select distinct this_.id as y0_ 
from MyTable this_ 
where this_.approved=1 
  and this_.related_id in (22205, 23805, 42987, 43750, 43868, 50773, 50774, 50776, 51996, 53719, 58947) 
order by this_.name asc, 
         this_.id asc 
limit 50;
```

**EDIT 3** - Info requested from comments

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(180) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `checkedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(180) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(180) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `import_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `related_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `approved` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `MyTable_1_idx` (`source_id`),
  KEY `MyTable_2_idx` (`name`),
  KEY `MyTable_3_idx` (`title`),
  KEY `MyTable_4_idx` (`description`),
  KEY `MyTable_5_idx` (`related_id`),
  KEY `MyTable_6_idx` (`import_id`),
  KEY `MyTable_7_idx` (`payment_id`),
  KEY `MyTable_8_idx` (`type_id`),
  KEY `MyTable_9_idx` (`related_id`,`name`),
  KEY `MyTable_10_idx` (`updatedDate`),
  KEY `MyTable_11_idx` (`approved`,`related_id`),
  KEY `MyTable_12_idx` (`related_id`,`approved`),
  KEY `MyTable_13_idx` (`related_id`,`checkedDate`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=49699672 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 29316578 |
+----------+
1 row in set (7.40 sec)

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     5403 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     2492 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type  | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                     | key           | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | MyTable | index | PRIMARY,MyTable_1_idx,MyTable_2_idx,MyTable_3_idx,MyTable_4_idx,MyTable_5_idx,MyTable_6_idx,MyTable_7_idx,MyTable_8_idx,MyTable_9_idx,MyTable_10_idx,MyTable_11_idx,MyTable_12_idx,MyTable_13_idx | MyTable_9_idx | 550     | NULL | 28960887 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+---------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I updated the table with `ALTER TABLE MyTable FORCE` last night to update the temporal columns for 5.6.  I'm not sure if it was that, or updated statistics or whatnot, but now it IS using an index, but it looks like it's only using the `name` portion to order, not filtering on `related_id`.  It is still slow enough that I cancelled it after a minute or so.

I also added the `FORCE INDEX` query/output below on the index that worked in 5.1, it refuses to use it:

```
explain extended 
select distinct this_.id as y0_ 
from MyTable this_ FORCE INDEX(MyTable_5_idx) 
where this_.related_id in (22205, 23805, 42987, 43750, 43868, 50773, 50774, 50776) 
order by this_.name asc, this_.id asc 
limit 50;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                     | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | this_ | ALL  | PRIMARY,MyTable_1_idx,MyTable_2_idx,MyTable_3_idx,MyTable_4_idx,MyTable_5_idx,MyTable_6_idx,MyTable_7_idx,MyTable_8_idx,MyTable_9_idx,MyTable_10_idx,MyTable_11_idx,MyTable_12_idx,MyTable_13_idx | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 28960887 |     0.03 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

After adding the following index however, I get the following plan, and almost instant execution:

```
alter table MyTable 
add index MyTable_14_idx (name, id, related_id), 
LOCK=None;

+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                                    | key            | key_len | ref  | rows     | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | this_ | index | PRIMARY,MyTable_1_idx,MyTable_2_idx,MyTable_3_idx,MyTable_4_idx,MyTable_5_idx,MyTable_6_idx,MyTable_7_idx,MyTable_8_idx,MyTable_9_idx,MyTable_10_idx,MyTable_11_idx,MyTable_12_idx,MyTable_13_idx,MyTable_14_idx | MyTable_14_idx | 558     | NULL | 28960887 |     0.03 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------+--------------------------+
```

I'm still not comfortable that this entirely fixes things however.  The query is built dynamically from a whole variety of user inputs, and the `ORDER BY` column itself can and will change, along with the filter criteria.  It seems that it should still be capable of using the `related_id` index to filter the results.  Thoughts?

Comment: This is interesting, to confirm it is a regression, could you write here the output of: `SHOW CREATE TABLE MyTable; SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable; SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE related_id = 22205; SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE related_id = 23805; EXPLAIN select distinct MyTable.id from MyTable where related_id in (22205, 23805) order by name asc, id asc limit 50;`

Comment: I wonder why MySQL even allows this query. It should refuse to use the `name` in `ORDER BY` when the select list does not have this column (name). This is not valid SQL. I also wonder what this query is supposed to do.

Comment: @jynus This is obviously a dumbed down example, so I'm trying to create as compact a test case as I can.  My first attempt with only the mentioned fields used an index as expected, so obviously the rest of the data is impacting things somehow.  Creating attempt number 2 right now, I'll get back to you shortly hopefully.

Comment: @ypercube Unless I'm terribly confused, both MySQL and Postgres allow an ORDER BY field that's not selected.  This query was actually generated by Hibernate, I just pulled out the noise.  As for the purpose, it's pulling the records matching the provided search criteria ultimately to paginate through them.  So, we need the first 50 records sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @Jafoy all DBMS allow a column not selected to be in the ORDER BY (if it could have been but for whatever reason it is not wanted in the Select list). But not with `SELECT DISTINCT`. You can test it in Oracle, SQL-Server, DB2, Postgres. They all forbid it.

Comment: Unless you severely changed the query during the simplification. Can you provide the full query?

Comment: I didn't change all that much, but added the original above, minus a few column/field renames.  And you're right, Postgres doesn't allow it, just double-checked, but MySQL appears to.  Another deviation from the standard it would seem.

Comment: It would be interesting to check if the execution plan differs with an index on `(related_id, id, name)`.

Comment: @jynus Added the requested output

Comment: @ypercube, I added that index, it didn't help, but the `(name, id, related_id index)` DID help, but seems very specific for what's ultimately a dynamically built query.

Comment: Will the `IN` list have only 2 values or it could be longer (with tens or hundreds of values)?

Comment: @ypercube It could be longer (the original/real query had 12 or so, I reduced it to 2 during testing), probably in the tens though rather than hundreds.

Comment: Last questions: If you change the query to `ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 50;` is it more efficient? And is there a problem with that (removing order by `name`)? It looks useless to me.

Comment: Yeah, business requirements.  We've been allowing an alpha sort by name for so long that we can't take it away now.  It performs a bit better, using the primary key to sort, but it still takes too long (13 seconds initial, 3-4 subsequent, in a quiet database vs .5 seconds in the live production 5.1 database).  Ideally I really need a way to filter by related_id again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a workaround, though I'm going to file a bug report unless someone can explain why this works.

The problem appears to originate with the `id` portion of the `order by` clause.  When using either

```
order by name asc,
         name asc,
         id asc
```

or

```
order by name asc,
         id asc,
         id asc
```

then the query uses the existing indices on `related_id` and the results come back instantly.  I had another similar query, and it was solved by changing this

```
order by id asc
```

to this

```
order by id asc,
         id asc
```

This makes absolutely no sense to me, but it works, and it all seems to be focused on the presence of `order by id`.